# How to toggle checkboxes that are linked to a specific range?

Tags: excel, vba

I have checkboxes that are LINKED to their own respective cells. When I check checkbox1, I want all the checkboxes in a specific range to be checked/unchecked.

Here is what I Used but it's not working. It's giving me error `Object variable or With block variable not set`.

```
Sub SelectAll_Click()
    Dim xCheckBox As CheckBox
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Range("B19:B28")

    For Each cell In rng
        If xCheckBox.Name <> Application.ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Name Then
            xCheckBox.Value = Application.ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: You never set ```xCheckBox```

Comment: @Warcupine what should I write ?

Comment: I'm unsure what you're going for here, but it seems like you want to loop through checkboxes and not cells?

Comment: The checkboxes are linked to their respective cells. I just want to checked/uncheck the Range(B19:B28) whenever checkbox1 is checked/unchecked

Comment: AFAIK, you can't refer to a checkbox by the cell, you need to get fancy with naming them to do so. If you loop through the checkboxes you can get the cell though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To toggle a `checkbox` that is linked to a cell you can simply set the cell value (or return value from a formula) to either `True` or `False`.

Using your example it would look something like:

```vb
Sub SelectAll_Click()
    Dim xCheckBox As CheckBox
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Range("B19:B28")

    For Each cell In rng
        cell.value = True
    Next cell
End Sub
```

---

If you need logic based on the checkbox itself then you would instead loop the checkboxes rather than the a range.

```vb
Private Sub demoLoopingCheckboxes()
    Dim control As OLEObject
    For Each control In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        With control
            ' The type of activex control
            ' Use this is a if statement to limit to only "CheckBox"
            Debug.Print TypeName(.Object)
            
            ' The cell Address to the linked cell
            Debug.Print .LinkedCell
            
            ' Can read/write the value to the checkbox itself
            Debug.Print .Object.Value
        End With
    Next control
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.